# Filter wordpress comments by user role

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

Trying to filter all my comments by a specific user role. In this case, the user role is called group1.  This will return all comments only when I remove `WHERE m.meta_key = 'wp_capabilities' AND m.meta_value = 'group1'`
from the query below.

```
$query = $wpdb->prepare( "
SELECT *
  FROM $wpdb->comments c
  LEFT 
  JOIN $wpdb->commentmeta cm 
    ON c.comment_ID = cm.comment_id
  LEFT 
  JOIN $wpdb->users u 
    ON c.user_id = u.ID
  LEFT 
  JOIN $wpdb->usermeta m 
    ON m.user_id = u.ID
 WHERE c.comment_post_ID = %s
   AND c.comment_approved = 1
 WHERE m.meta_key = 'wp_capabilities'
   AND m.meta_value = 'group1'
 ORDER 
    BY c.comment_ID $comment_order
                    ",
                    $post->ID);
```

Comment: This will return a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

You have two `WHERE` clauses, but even on fixing the syntax error, it'll work as `inner join` as the filter conditions for the outer table in the where clause turn an outer join into an inner join.

Add the filters for outer tables in the `LEFT JOIN`'s `ON` clause itself:

```
select *
from $wpdb - > comments c
left join $wpdb - > commentmeta cm on c.comment_ID = cm.comment_id
left join $wpdb - > users u on c.user_id = u.ID
left join $wpdb - > usermeta m on m.user_id = u.ID
    and m.meta_key = 'wp_capabilities'
    and m.meta_value = 'group1'
where c.comment_post_ID = % s
    and c.comment_approved = 1
order by c.comment_ID $comment_order
```

Comment: I updated and the query and some values are missing from the array: the user ID, and the umeta_id.